# Understanding the prioritised_handlers.cpp example from boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using `boost::asio`, and I'm trying to control the order my handlers are called in.  I was pointed at the `prioritised_handlers.cpp` example.  When I tried to adapt it, I didn't get the behavior I expected.  When I pass a handler to `io_service.post` from within a handler, the handler is never run.

I started trying to find the smallest example of the behavior I don't understand.  So, make the following modification to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp

Simple example:

```
161   while (io_service.run_one())
162   {
163     // The custom invocation hook adds the handlers to the priority
164     // queue
165     // rather than executing them from within the poll_one() call.
166     while (io_service.poll_one())
167       ;
168     io_service.post(pri_queue.wrap(1, low_priority_handler));
169 
170     pri_queue.execute_all();
171 
172   }
```

Comment: The comment obviously screwed it up.

Comment: I should be clearer about what's wrong.  The issue is that low_priority_handler only actually runs once.  I think it should run twice.

Comment: you only post it once. I'm pretty sure it's only supposed to be called once.